# How to disable the "minimum successful builds" requirement for Bitbucket Cloud pull requests?

Tags: merge, pull-request, bitbucket-cloud

I want to allow my users to disable the "minumum successful builds" requirement in the Bitbucket Cloud pull request merge checklist. How can I do this?

Some of our PRs are for documentation edits that have no effect on compiled or executed code. While a review is necessary before the PR can be merged, a build is not necessary.

I have been through the Repository Settings and Pull Request settings pages for this repo. I have reviewed the Bitbucket Cloud online documentation. I haven't found an enable/disable or select/deselect switch for "minimum successful" builds. I did find a spinner for the number of minimum successful builds, but it starts at 1, not 0.